# Restrict amount of times jQuery slider fires change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, jquery-mobile, flask

I have the problem that the jQuery mobile slider fires too often to get handled properly on the server. I have something like this:

```
$("#testSlider").change(function( event, ui ) {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_update_sliders', {
        c: $('#testSlider').val()
  }, function(data) {
    g4.updateOptions( { 'file': data.result } );


      });
```

This works perfectly fine, /_update_sliders starts a function in python which sends data.result back to the site. The problem occurs if I change the slider too fast - too many requests are send, when I stop the slider it takes quite some time too catch up and it even mixes up the requests - so the end state might not even present the actual slider value.

What is a clean solution to this? Anyway to restrict the amount of times the change event fires up?

Thank you and kind regards

lakerz

Answer (score 3):

You could put a throttle on it using following concept. Uses setTimeout() to add delay, and if changes are constantly happening delay gets pushed back and it will not fire until a full delay period has ended

```js
var sliderTimer,
    sliderAjaxDelay = 100;

$("#testSlider").change(function (event, ui) {
    if (sliderTimer) {
        clearTimout(sliderTimer); /* if already a timeout, clear it */
    }

    // throttle requests using setTimeout 
    sliderTimer = setTimeout(sliderAjaxUpdate, sliderAjaxDelay);
});   


function sliderAjaxUpdate() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_update_sliders', {
        c: $('#testSlider').val()
    }, function (data) {
        g4.updateOptions({
            'file': data.result
        });
    });
}
```

Adjust the delay variable to what suits you

Comment: Thank you very much. The code itself works, but not the way I want it to behave - e.g., when I permanently move the slider, it doesn't update my data at all. Sure, because it always resets the timeout. What I want instead is, that it does update as often as possible, but **only** when the preceding request has finished.

Comment: What is this being used for?

Comment: I'm plotting a graph, and the line data changes with a parameter that I set using a slider. So every time the slider changes, the points of the line get recalculated and send back to the client to redraw. I found a solution with the jQuery ajaxComplete function, although I'm not sure if this is a clean way (see my answer).

Comment: Using a flag was my alternate thought. Would use the flag on the cchange handler though not `ajaxComplete` because that will trigger for all other ajax calls in the page also

Comment: How do you mean? I mean, how could I set the flag in change, when change gets called way to often?

Comment: set it inside handler and inside the ajax callback. Don't make request if one in progress

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in jQuery which works, but I'm not sure if this is a "clean" way:

```
var complete = 0;

$("#testSlider").change(function (event, ui) {
    if (complete == 1) {
        sliderAjaxUpdate();
        complete = 0;
    };

});

function sliderAjaxUpdate() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_update_sliders', {
        c: $('#testSlider').val()
    }, function (data) {
        g4.updateOptions({
            'file': data.result
        });
    });
};

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  complete = 1;
});
```